# How to return a result at the moment of an interrupt a.k.a. how to retrieve the result of a Callable although it's cancelled

Tags: java, optimization, interrupt, future, callable

I've grown desperate all night on this problem and I have not found help during online research, so here we go.

I want to do an optimization process which is meant to be interrupted at a time that is being determined on runtime. Once the interrupt is thrown, I want the best result that has been calculated until that moment to be returned.

My Idea was to put the calculations into a Callable. Because Callables can return results and also - at least I thought - be interrupted. My call() method would be able to return my best result when an interrupt is thrown. But apparently, the only way to force an interrupt into the Callable is to do `task.cancel(true);` which then throws a CancellationException before `result = task.get();` can retrieve the result.

A rough scetch of my code:

```
SearchCallable myCallable = new myCallable(...);
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
Future<int[]> task = service.submit(myCallable);

try {
  Thread.sleep(getTimeToCalculate(...));
} catch (InterruptedException e) {[...]}

task.cancel(true);

try {
  result = task.get();
} catch(InterruptedException ie){[...]
} catch (ExecutionException ee) {[...]}
```

myCallable looks somewhat like this:

```
public class myCallable implements Callable<Object> {
  public myCallable(...){
    [...]
  }

  public Object call(){
    return anObjectOfAnotherClass.saidCalculations();
  }
}
```

Where an auxiliary method which does a lot of recursion contains this:

```
    if(Thread.interrupted()){

        throw new InterruptedException();
    }
```

And said auxiliary  method catches this InterruptedException and returns it's best result so far, so myCallable gets this result and actually should return it.

So, how can I get the interrupt in there and still get my result? Or is there some completely different way to implement my original idea?

Comment: Can you define "best result"? Do the results of your computation implement `Comparable`?

Comment: Must I understand that your result is in fact _one_ result, run by one thread, but the "best result" is "the best it could come up until it was killed"?

Comment: It just compares integer values of evaluated objects and during execution always remembers the object with the best value. So yes, "the best it could come up until it was killed" it is. And yes, just one thread, though it doesn't necessarily has to be done in a thread.

Comment: Maybe I am overloking something, but why don't you move logic to thread -> store after each iteration the best value in an accessible (via getter!) attribute -> keep a reference to the thread in the main method -> after interrupting the thread, retrieve the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there is *one* thread performing the computation; this thread is interrupted and the "best result" is what it could come up with.

Then you can, instead of a `Callable`, use a `Runnable` and pass a reference to a structure bearing the result when you initialize it.

You can then submit that runnable to your thread pool; when it is "done with its work" (either it is really done, or it was interrupted), you'll just have to read the data in the reference you passed to your `Runnable` as an argument.

**EDIT** Since the result of the computation is a( reference to a)n object, I suggest the use of an [`AtomicReference`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html).