# How to return a result at the moment of an interrupt in Java Future

Tags: java, concurrency, future

I have a list of tasks which I submit using execution service. I am using time bounded execution of a thread and waiting result in a future object. But now I want to collect the result when the callable thread gets interrupted. I have a result, but I can't perform future.get() as it is already cancelled due to timeout. How can I store the partial results in the future object?

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129275/how-to-return-a-result-at-the-moment-of-an-interrupt-a-k-a-how-to-retrieve-the

Answer (score 0):

You should get an exception when the timebound thread is interrupted.

```
Future<String> future = executorService.submit(callableTask);
String result = null;
try {
    result = future.get();
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Yes. Agree, but how should i take result when the exception occured in future.get()?